# Styling a single department/small population in Mapbox Studio

Tags: android, maps, overlay, mapbox

I've got a question related to Mapbox Studio, later being used in Android.
I'm developing an app which's main function is to inform the population about alerts of any kind, such as climatical, massive movements or security.
In order to do this, I'd like to style a map of my country (Uruguay, img) in a department level (the boundaries are displayed on the sample image), so I could color a single department in red when there's an alert or noticeable event. How can I achieve this? I've tried to introduce myself in tilesets-datasets but I think I'm complicating the thing much more than I should.

[image: img1]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need add a new layer in Mapbox Studio with a Shapefile (or similar - i.e GeoJSON) to outline the administrative boundaries.

If its non commercial you can find administrative boundaries here: http://www.gadm.org (there are boundaries for Uruguay)

The data you wish to present at administrative boundary level (climate, security etc..) can be added into the shapefile into respective columns. If the data is going to be live or changing you can push the data with Mapbox GL real-time on the android device.